# How do you prevent ckeditor5 from stripping out custom classes, styles and comments?

Tags: datatables, editor, ckeditor5

We are looking at a project which involves enabling a wysiwyg editor in DataTables editor.

DTE has plugins for CKE, TinyMCE and I think Quill. CKEditor5 works in DTE however when you  go to edit content we can't get to what we need. Example - this is the code we copy in using source code:

```
<!-- Section -->
<section id="faq" class="faq section-bg">
  <div class="container" data-aos="fade-up">
    <div class="faq-list">
      <ul>

        <li data-aos="fade-up" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="100">
          <i class="bx bx-help-circle icon-help"></i> <a data-bs-toggle="collapse" class="collapse" data-bs-target="#faq-list-1">Non consectetur a erat nam at lectus urna duis? <i class="bx bx-chevron-down icon-show"></i><i class="bx bx-chevron-up icon-close"></i></a>
          <div id="faq-list-1" class="collapse show" data-bs-parent=".faq-list">
            <p>
              Feugiat pretium nibh ipsum consequat. Tempus iaculis urna id volutpat lacus laoreet non curabitur gravida. Venenatis lectus magna fringilla urna porttitor rhoncus dolor purus non.
            </p>
          </div>
        </li>

        <li data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="200">
          <i class="bx bx-help-circle icon-help"></i> <a data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#faq-list-2" class="collapsed">Feugiat scelerisque varius morbi enim nunc? <i class="bx bx-chevron-down icon-show"></i><i class="bx bx-chevron-up icon-close"></i></a>
          <div id="faq-list-2" class="collapse" data-bs-parent=".faq-list">
            <p>
              Dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit pellentesque habitant morbi. Id interdum velit laoreet id donec ultrices. Fringilla phasellus faucibus scelerisque eleifend donec pretium. Est pellentesque elit ullamcorper dignissim. Mauris ultrices eros in cursus turpis massa tincidunt dui.
            </p>
          </div>
        </li>

        <li data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="300">
          <i class="bx bx-help-circle icon-help"></i> <a data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#faq-list-3" class="collapsed">Dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit? <i class="bx bx-chevron-down icon-show"></i><i class="bx bx-chevron-up icon-close"></i></a>
          <div id="faq-list-3" class="collapse" data-bs-parent=".faq-list">
            <p>
              Eleifend mi in nulla posuere sollicitudin aliquam ultrices sagittis orci. Faucibus pulvinar elementum integer enim. Sem nulla pharetra diam sit amet nisl suscipit. Rutrum tellus pellentesque eu tincidunt. Lectus urna duis convallis convallis tellus. Urna molestie at elementum eu facilisis sed odio morbi quis
            </p>
          </div>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</section><!-- Section -->
```

After  I switch back to formatting view it strips  out classes, comments, data-, etc. We need it to not do this so that non-tech-savvy people can edit the text with the formatting editor  enabled. Here is what you see after switching to  format editor view:

```
<ul>
    <li class="faq section-bg" id="faq">
        <a class="collapse" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#faq-list-1">Non consectetur a erat nam at lectus urna duis?&nbsp;</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<p class="faq section-bg" id="faq">
    Feugiat pretium nibh ipsum consequat. Tempus iaculis urna id volutpat lacus laoreet non curabitur gravida. Venenatis lectus magna fringilla urna porttitor rhoncus dolor purus non.
</p>
<ul>
    <li class="faq section-bg" id="faq">
        <a class="collapsed" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#faq-list-2">Feugiat scelerisque varius morbi enim nunc?&nbsp;</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<p class="faq section-bg" id="faq">
    Dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit pellentesque habitant morbi. Id interdum velit laoreet id donec ultrices. Fringilla phasellus faucibus scelerisque eleifend donec pretium. Est pellentesque elit ullamcorper dignissim. Mauris ultrices eros in cursus turpis massa tincidunt dui.
</p>
<ul>
    <li class="faq section-bg" id="faq">
        <a class="collapsed" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#faq-list-3">Dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit?&nbsp;</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I looked at the plugin list and found HTMLembed but I don't see this solving the need. If not ckeditor5 is there an open source editor that can be used in DTE to meet this need - or - what do we do to customize it to make it  work?

Comment: HTMLembed did not help. It added a space where we could add  code view of HTML but there is no way to switch the  code into a formatting toolbar view and turn it over to an unskilled person to edit.